# Unity2D: Mirror Multiplying - How to view an opponent's screen in a match 3 game

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, unity3d-mirror

I'm making my own match 3 multiplayer game, the concept is to have two people face off against each other person can face off another person by swapping tiles to make a line of the same form. I want to introduce multiplayer by connecting two players together and allowing each person to see their opponent's screen, as well as syncing their moves. So far, I have a simple match 3 game (I created one using different tutorials, mainly this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcXoKw-RRgk&list=PL4vbr3u7UKWrxEz75MqmTDd899cYAvQ_B)) and followed a simple multiplayer tutorial (Mirror) for a player to host or be a client. My problem is that I have no idea how to show both players their opponent's screen to each other. I even found an example of what I want the multiplayer mode in my game to be [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqpVN.jpg). Can anyone point me in the right direction, please and thank you.

Additional information:

I'm using mirror for multiplayer

I created a network manager gameobject and added the necessary components to it. I also added the game pieces into the 'registered spawnable prefabs' and created an empty gameobject, called player for the player prefab.

Each game piece has a network transform and network identity component attached.

The player prefab object has a camera child under it to.

This is what I want my game to look like:

[image]

Overall, I want to have player's view each other's screen:

[image]

As you can see, both player's are connected, what I want to do it to allow each player see their opponent's screen. Does anyone have an idea on how I can do it?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Well a) make a "screenshot" and display it on the other side or b) actually synchronize the objects etc and rebuild it on the other side ...

Comment: If both players play their own board, then you should have 2 instances of the boards in your game and synchronize them both, each player must be able to interact with only 1 board.